# What type of galvanometer is in this picture?

Tags: voltage, inductor, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, history

Does anyone understand the galvanometer in Faraday's experiment to the left in the picture below? How does it operate? It looks like it uses a magnet and some xy axis the needle swings over or maybe the disc spins. There is what looks like a coil of wire under the disc and unsure if that’s an inductor. Also unsure about the two posts inside the apparatus if they carry current as well.

[image]

Ref [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction)

Comment: Nick. A question: *Did you notice in the linked page that the given picture includes a reference?* If you click on that reference and actually ***read it*** then you will know exactly what that device called **G** is and how to make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be an [astatic galvanometer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanometer#Astatic_galvanometer) in the drawing of Faraday's demonstration of the law of induction.

In an astatic galvanometer, there's a support (the two "posts") from which a fine thread suspends two needles.  There's a coil under the scale to drive the needles.